# How to show a popup menu on an anchor

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, contextmenu

I am making a fairly complex front page that in essence is a threaded discussion forum. At present all is functional but I want to replace the links after the message that allow one to delete, reply, archive and other functions. At present the links are all text. I can use small images and make them look nicer. However on a busy front page with lots of messages and threads a whole bunch of images will make the whole page look overwhelming.

The way it works for now is each iteration of the call to function that reads a message from db will start a ul and this allows me to nicely pad the child messages and the depth.

Here is what I want to do - create a small popup menu that will show up when someone hovers over the actual message. Because my current way of showing threaded messages using ul and li when I tried to use jqueryui menu widget it wrecks the formatting.

Sorry about all the rambling but is there a way to show a slim line of links above a message when someone hovers over it and each message in the page will obviously need to have different links [to allow blah.php?messageid=...].

I have been looking at jqueryui and learnt it to a tiny extent and still reading the tutorial. Is there a way of doing what I asked above!

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but check out this link : http://marcosesperon.es/apps/messi/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple way to do this is as follows:

given markup

```
<div class="menu-pop">
    <div class="menu-label">Menu Label</div>
    <div class="menu-items">
        <div class="menu-item">menu choice</div>
        <div class="menu-item">menu choice</div>
        <div class="menu-item">menu choice</div>
        <div class="menu-item">menu choice</div>
        <div class="menu-item">menu choice</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

provide css:

```
.menu-pop {
    position: relative;
}

.menu-pop .menu-items {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.menu-pop.dropped .menu-items {
    display:inherit;
}
```

and a simple jquery function:

```
$(".menu-pop").hover(
        function() { $(this).addClass("dropped"); }, 
        function() { $(this).removeClass("dropped" ); }
    );
```

then ... well ... make it pretty.

see the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DomDay/rmSHc/

Comment: The trouble I have is I really want to avoid using any ul or ol as my threaded messaging already depends on the ul/li and for each of the children of the message it recursively calls itself and formats the indentation and so on nicely. If I can help it I want to avoid any ul/ol/li. Is there a different way?

Comment: I saw the code where you used div. I will try it now and see.

Comment: The last example you gave looks like it will work. I am going to try this. I am trying your example now. My front page gets generated over several functions in segments. So I am implementing this in one function to test it out. Is there a similar but quicker to write way with jquery? - quicker and prettier perhaps! I know, I know I am getting greedy. Thanks for help all.

Comment: sure, see edit of original answer ... it's ... um ... tidier that way

Comment: Thanks Dom Day. That worked. My version looks ugly at present but now that I have something to work on I can beautify it. Now off to fighting with accordion! I have been doing fair amount of programming with python and c++, done a reasonable amount of js but barely used css and didn't use jquery until now. A steep learning curve indeed. Slowly getting there. This site has been a saver on a number of occasions. Shame it does not let me thumbs up.

Comment: glad to help. I tried to keep it as simple as possible. For what it's worth, once you get jquery, everything becomes easier. ( I can't thumbs-up either )

Answer (score 2):

Your looking for `tooltip`, Jquery UI has a [tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

first you initialize the tooltip, this example initialize it for the whole document.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });
  </script>
```

Then you add your tags and use the `title` attribute to specify what you wish to have for tooltip.

```
<p><label for="age">Your age:</label><input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes." /></p>
```

Comment: I just tried that. I generated a set of anchors, put them in a table and passed that as the title to the li. However when I hover over it it just shows me the raw html instead of showing it as a table of links :-)